# Populating entries in ConcurrentMap<String, CompletableFuture<Object>> in java

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I am starting with the concept of `CompletableFuture` in java. I have a use case where I need to populate a values in `Map<String, CompletableFuture<Object>>`.

Assuming there is a Student entity class and a `ConcurrentMap<String, CompletableFuture<Student>>`. I tried to populate student entries into the map in following way:

```
Student student = new Student();
ConcurrentMap<String, CompletableFuture<Student>> studentMap = new ConcurrentMap<>();

CompletableFuture<Student> studentcf = new CompletableFuture<>();
studentcf.complete(student); // Not sure whether it is the right way to convert a entity into CompletableFuture

studentMap.put("Alex", studentcf);
```

The above solution worked but I am not sure whether it is the right way to do this (converting the entity to CompletableFuture). Can someone please suggest me the right way to do the above scenario?

Any suggestions will be helpful!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are you instantiating `CompletableFuture` objects with `new`? These objects should be returned to you by an executor service, not constructed by you.

Comment: There is too little information about the actual use case. When the object does already exist, why are you using `CompletableFuture` at all? There are legitimate use cases for constructing an already completed future, e.g. when the operation is asynchronous *sometimes*, so you can use `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(student)`. There are also cases where a plain `put(key, value)` on a `ConcurrentMap` is sufficient, but it’s impossible to judge here, when we don’t know why you are using a `ConcurrentMap` at all. For the things we see here, a simple `Map<String,Student>` would do.

Answer (score 2):

The above code is possible, but it doesn't make much sense. `CompletableFuture` is used for asynchronous calls. When the result of an operation is not known immediately, but only after some time.

Example:

```
    public Future<Student> calculateAsync() throws InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<Student> completableFuture 
          = new CompletableFuture<>();
     
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Student student = new Student();
            completableFuture.complete(student); //completed after 5 seconds
            return null;
        });
     
        return completableFuture; //return immediately
    }
    
    Future<Student> completableFuture = calculateAsync();
     
    // ... 
     
    Student result = completableFuture.get(); //This call is blocked until the result, which is generated by the embedded thread, is known.
```

Comment: Don’t create a thread pool for a single job. Don’t let it hang around and hope that the garbage collector will shut it down for you. For the operation you have shown, just use `return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Student::new);`, the tool designed for such a job.